# Why can't I use adb to make a phonecall on real phone?

Tags: android, adb

I have tried to use the following to initiate a phone call:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:12345`

It can work on a virtual device. But on a real phone, there are no responses.
By the way, the following can work on the real one:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d tel:1234`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try to use launch the intent using your device serial number , Use adb devices to get your phone's serial number and then : adb -s put_serial_here shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:put_number_here

Comment: Even I use the serial number, it doesn't work.

Comment: do you have multiple devices connected? I tried this and worked. what happens when you run this command?